# Distribution with compact support

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

In my book I have seen that if I have a disitribution $T$ in $D'$ (continuous linear functional on the space $D$) which can be defined for every $C^{\infty}$ function
(no necessarily compact supported ) then $T$ must have compact support since otherwise we can construct $\phi\in C^{\infty}$ such that $\langle T,\phi\rangle$ is not finite.

Does anyone have idea how to construct such function?

thank you

Comment: What is the space $D$?

Comment: space of $C^{\infty}$ functions with compact support

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that the support of $T$ is not compact. Then this support intersects with infinite number of intervals of the form $[n,n+1]$, $n\in\Bbb Z$. Denote the indices of intervals that intersect with the support of $T$ by $n_k$, $k\in \Bbb Z$.

Now, $\forall k\in \Bbb Z$ there exist a test function $\phi_k$ with support in $[n_k,n_k+1]$ such that $(T,\phi_k)=1$ (this quickly follows from our definition of $n_k$ and from linearity of $T$).

The function $\Phi(x)=\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}\phi_k(x)$ is $C^\infty(\Bbb R)$. Yet $$(T,\Phi) = \sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}(T,\phi_k(x))=\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}1=+\infty.$$

Comment: Why does $T(\Phi)$ equal that infinite sum?

Comment: @zhw. the linearity of $T$ and the "disjointness" of supports of $\phi_k$ should suffice.

Comment: You need the continuity of $T$ on the metric space $C^\infty$  I would think.

Comment: @zhw. That's a good remark. Why this space? I'd say that the seminorms should be along the lines of $p_{R,k}(\phi) = \sup_{|x|<R}|\phi^{(k)}(x)|$.

Comment: Those semi norms are exactly the ones that turn $C^\infty$ into a metric space.

Comment: @zhw. I see. I thought that the seminorms for $C^\infty$ are $p_k(\phi)=\sup_{x\in \Bbb R}|\phi^{(k)}(x)|$.

Comment: If that were true, then your sum wouldn't converge in $C^\infty.$ What I'm saying is, your idea works if we have the usual topology on $C^\infty$ - but this needs to be made clear ahead of time.